# compare dfs which do not have unique value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1:

 Parameters TrueResult     
 Defaults    authenticate  
 xyz         ALL             

df2:  
Parameters   ConfigResult       
 Defaults    authenticate     
  xyz        noone
```

I have 2 dataframes. I created them from 2 different text file.
Case is:
I will compare a file's configuration with true results.
df1 has true results for given parameters.
df2 has the given file's configurations.

```
Expected Output:

 Parameters TrueResult      ConfigResult     AuditResult
 Defaults    authenticate    authenticate     ok
 xyz         ALL             noone            analyze
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi, I added expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the below:

```
In [1054]: import numpy as np

In [1055]: res = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Parameters'),df2.set_index('Parameters')],axis=1).reset_index()

In [1058]: res['AuditResult'] = np.where(res.TrueResult.eq(res.ConfigResult), 'ok', 'analyze')

In [1059]: res
Out[1059]: 
  Parameters    TrueResult   ConfigResult AuditResult
0   Defaults      envreset      !envreset     analyze
1   Defaults  mail_badpass  !mail_badpass     analyze
2   Defaults  authenticate   authenticate          ok
3        xyz           ALL          noone     analyze
```

Comment: this is ok I guess but when I applied Audit result field is full of analyze, I'm trying to understand

Comment: Yes, logic behind `AuditResult` is, If `TrueResult` matches `ConfigResult` then `ok`, otherwise `analyze`. Is this not the right logic? Let me know if there's something else.

Comment: yes thats right but when I applied the code I get only analyze even the data is same :)

Comment: That's weird. The only explanation is that your data has `whitespaces` which is why it is not doing an exact string match. Can you check this?

Comment: Yes, df2 ConfigResult  column has whitespaces at the end of each string

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential solution. You can first [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the dataframes and then use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

- `pd.concat:`

```
>>> df_merged = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Parameters'),df2.set_index('Parameters')],axis=1).reset_index()

##df_merged
  Parameters    TrueResult   ConfigResult
0   Defaults      envreset      !envreset
1   Defaults  mail_badpass  !mail_badpass
2   Defaults  authenticate   authenticate
3        xyz           ALL          noone
```

- `apply`:

```
>>> d = {True:'analyze', False:'ok'}
>>> df_merged['AuditResult'] = df_merged.apply(lambda x : x['TrueResult']!=x['ConfigResult'],axis=1 ).map(d)
```

**Output**:

```
  Parameters    TrueResult   ConfigResult AuditResult
0   Defaults      envreset      !envreset     analyze
1   Defaults  mail_badpass  !mail_badpass     analyze
2   Defaults  authenticate   authenticate          ok
3        xyz           ALL          noone     analyze
```

Comment: I don't think your output matches the output that OP wants.

Comment: @MayankPorwal What is the problem with my answer/output. I couldn't figure out.

Comment: The number of rows in your `df_merged` are more than what OP wants. This is because since the values of `Parameters` is not unique, it is joining each row of `df1` with each row of `df2`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Okay. Thanks a lot. Perhaps `pd.concat ` with `parameters` as index. It worked with `pd.read_clipboard()`

Comment: `apply` is generally slower. You can check my answer which uses `numpy.where`.

Comment: Sure. I didn't like `apply` solution either. `np.where`/`assign`  is better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

First merge 2 dfs then use assign function to analyze two columns and create third column:

```
df = pd.concat([
     df1.assign(Parameters = lambda x: x['Parameters'].str.strip()),
     df2.assign(Parameters = lambda x: x['Parameters'].str.strip())
], axis=1).assign(AuditResult= lambda x: np.where(x['TrueResult'] == x['ConfigResult'],"OK","analyze"))
```

Comment: Perhaps you need a space cleanup on your parameter values. I updated to do a trim on your parameter values

Comment: `df.assign` is a good approach. Added the missing quotes in `X[configResult]` in your answer.